# Curly braces and nested arrays

Tags: equations, arrays

I am trying to reproduce the equation of the image below. I am using an `array` environment to create the first big curly brace. I have tried to nest a second `array` to produce a second curly brace, but I get an error.

[image]

This is the code that gave me an error:

```
DTW(A,B)=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
    0 \quad \text{se $n$=0 ed $m$=0}\\
    \infty \quad \text{se $n$=0 o $m$=0}\\
    d(H(A),H(B))+\min\left\{
    \begin{array}{1}
        a\\
        b\\
        c\\
    \end{array}
    \right.
  \end{array} \right.
```

How can I write this equation?

Comment: Please give the code giving the error.

Comment: The `{1}` after the inner `\begin{array}` should be `{l}` (an "ell", not a "one"). The error was `Illegal character in array arg`.

Comment: Not tested, but you have `1` (one) instead of `l` (ell) in the second array spec. - Gah, Ninja'd.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a typo in your inner array

change

```
     \begin{array}{1}
                   %%%
```

to

```
   \begin{array}{l}
                %%%
```

Comment: For those of you wondering what changed... the OP has '1' (one) and the edit changes it to 'l' (letter 'ell').

Answer (score 10):

To give you another possibility using `cases` from `amsmath` or `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
DTW(A,B)=\begin{cases}
    0 \quad \phantom{\infty}\text{if}\,\, n=0 \,\,\text{and}\,\, m=0  \\
    \infty \quad \phantom{0}  \text{if}\,\, n=0 \,\,\text{and}\,\, m=0 \\
    {d(H(A),H(B))+\min \begin{cases}
        a\\
        b\\
        c\\
    \end{cases}}
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation} 
  \end{document}
```

[image]